# Finding co-ordinates in multidimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have an `int[][]` array like so:

```
int[][] arr = { {3, 4, 3, 5, -9}, 
                {0, 4, 4, -8, 6}, 
                {1, 1, 3, -9, 6}, 
                {4, 3, -2, 5, 6}};
```

The actual problem is to find a rectangle in the 2-d array, that each corner of the rectangle has the same values as the corner elements in the 2-d array. For example, the corners are 3, -9, 4 and 6. And the resulting rectangle is the one at [0, 2], [0, 4], [1, 2], [1, 4].

My attempt is to first find out the positions of all the [3, -9]s on each row, so for example, the first row has two of them at [{0,0},{0,4}] and [{0,2},{0,4}].

I can do the standard nested `for` loops to find each 3, and each 9:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    // if value is 3, store the co-ordinates
    // if value is 9, store the co-ordinates (separately)
    }
}
```

But then I'm forced to loop through the 2 lists (of 3s and -9s) and check that for each 3, that there is a -9 on the same row, and that it's after it in that row, and if so, combine, and store, the two co-ordinates together.

Then of course I've to do the same with the 4s and 6s and it has quickly become a large mess.

Perhaps I'm looking at this all wrong, and could be considered an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

My question: how do I find a rectangle in the 2d-array with the corners of said rectangle matching the outer corners of the 2-d array?

Comment: First find upper left corner, then if it is at the far right column or bottom row disregard it, otherwise search at same row, to the right, for upper right corner and if found then search at same column, down, for lower left. Then if both found check that the lower right deducted from your found upper left and lower right  matches.

Answer (score 1):

What about plain search?

```
public static List<Point> findRectangle(int[][] arr) {
    int height = arr.length;
    int width = arr[0].length;

    for (int rowTop = 0; rowTop < height - 1; rowTop++) {
        for (int colLeft = rowTop == 0 ? 1 : 0; colLeft < width - 1; colLeft++) {
            // find new left-top corner
            if (arr[rowTop][colLeft] != arr[0][0])
                continue;

            int colRight = colLeft + 1;

            while (colRight < width && arr[rowTop][colRight] != arr[0][width - 1]) {
                colRight++;
            }

            if (colRight == width)
                continue;

            // find new left-bottom corner
            int rowBottom = rowTop + 1;

            while (rowBottom < height && arr[rowBottom][colLeft] != arr[height - 1][0]) {
                rowBottom++;
            }

            if (rowBottom == height || arr[rowBottom][colRight] != arr[height - 1][width - 1])
                continue;

            return Arrays.asList(
                    new Point(rowTop, colLeft),
                    new Point(rowTop, colRight),
                    new Point(rowBottom, colLeft),
                    new Point(rowBottom, colRight));
        }
    }

    return Collections.emptyList();
}

public static final class Point {

    private final int row;
    private final int col;

    public Point(int row, int col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Oleg - however it appears to be printing `[[0], [0], [0], [3], [3], [0], [3], [3]]` (with a simple `toString()` on `Point`)?

Comment: Just a moment. I can see couple of problems and fixing it.